# Google Earth Engine: loop raster extraction over image collection and create dataframes (geemap)

Tags: google-earth-engine, pandas, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I would like to extract a large number of points (approximately 3000) from each image within an image collection, and return a pandas dataframe for each image.

The function I'm using to extract raster values from images is:

```
def rasterExtraction(image):
    feature = image.sampleRegions(
        collection = points,
        scale = 30 
    )
    return feature
```

and the function I use to create the collection is:

```
years = range(2000, 2012)
def monthly_Avg (collection, years):
  avg = []
  for year in years: 
      Monthly_avg = collection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
                              .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(5, 10, 'month')) \
                              .mean() \
                              .set({'year': year})
      avg.append (Monthly_avg)
  return ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(avg)
```

I then apply the monthly_Avg function to a filtered image collection (with some cloud masking as well):

```
ls5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(points).map(maskL5sr)
av_ls5 = monthly_Avg(ls5, years = years)
```

And everything is working well until the final step: Extracting the values for my sampling locations (the `points` feature class in the rasterExtraction function) for each year within the image collection. As I have about 3000 points, I cannot do the following, as it raises over 5000 elements and returns an error:

```
df = geemap.ee_to_pandas(monthly_ls5.map(rasterExtraction).flatten())
```

Is there any way to get a pandas dataframe for each year's average values without going through images within the image collection manually?

Comment: Just very quickly, instead of merging the yearly image collections then create the data frame, you could perhaps generate a data frame for each year and merge them at the end?

Comment: So I have tried this and it does work, however, I'd prefer not to have to write this out for each year - especially since I plan on experimenting with the month range, which would involve going into each year and changing things significantly. My goal is to have code that is easily replicated, with minimal effort required to change the month/year range.

Comment: Update: That works! I was being dumb - I've got it working now. Thanks!